# Sync between variables and unity gui

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following GUI:
[image: The GUI]
As can be seen - this dialog has a title and two buttons.
The dialog title is label that i control using a property in a Dialog script, and the buttons are represented as OptionsButton.

What I want to do is to control these values from scripts, so if I set the title from the inspector - it'll be visible in editor mode and in play mode as initial value. Same deal goes to the texture - so if I'll set the texture from the inspector (not with Unity built-in inspector field but in my custom field) - it'll update both editor and play mode.

Lets take a better example with the title: for the title, I have the following property:

```
    [TabGroup("Game Objects")]
    [Required]
    public GameObject dialogTitleObject;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the dialog title.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The dialog title.</value>
    public string Title
    {
        get { return this.dialogTitleObject.GetComponent<UILabel>().text; }
        set { this.dialogTitleObject.GetComponent<UILabel>().text = value; }
    }
```

So, at runtime I **do** able to modify this value successfully. However - I want to have the following inspector:
[image: The inspector I want]
And it should be able to modify the value in the Editor Mode (not in Play Mode) the value will be modified accordingly.
Right now I can't do such thing and even if i type in the inspector textbox - nothing will happen.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after few days of reading and tweaking, I came to the solution I posted in this public gist: https://gist.github.com/YahavGB/dea6289a9bd6e6fba82885abbd8da820 . 
Basically, I've used a getter and setter methods instead of actual C# properties. Then I created a drawer that sync between the field and the methods.
Finally, to make sure i dont add extra fields, as I just needed to "forward" the call, and not to actually add another variable, I added a macro check for `UNITY_EDITOR`. Thus I do add another field ( :( ) but just in the editor and not in the actual production game.

I hope this solution will aid someone in the future.

Answer (score -3):

So basic you need build a Custom Inspector

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/building-custom-inspector

This will bind unity to variable.

Comment: My aim is to sync, or link, between a variable who already have an inspector field and one who doesn’t so when I’ll set a sprite in one place - it’ll update (by some logic) the sprite texture. Another example is the title - I’d want to add a title field to the ModalDialog mono behavior field which’s update the value of the UILabel.Text field - both internally and in editor mode. You can see by my code above that right now i do it with properties and it does work. The issue is, though, the actual linkage between the two. Rebuilding the inspector should be, IMO, last resort.